# Comparing string array to variable Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, foreach

I have a dilemma I am trying to find out the best way to compare a string variable called (code) to an array of strings. if it equal it i want it to break the for loop. Which would should I select. I think the 2nd one will work but the 1st one seems like it would and its simpler. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
String[] badcodes = {"8QQ", "8BQ", "8JQ"};
if (code.equals(badcodes)) {
    break;
}

String[] badcodess = {"8QQ", "8BQ", "8JQ"};
for (String s : badcodess) {
    if (s.equals(code)) {
        break; // break out of for loop
    }
}
```

--------------based on answer ----------------------

```
String[] badcodes = {"8QQ", "8BQ", "8JQ"};
boolean check = Arrays.asList(badcodess).contains(code);
if (check = true) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You mean, if any of the strings in the array equals the value of `code`?

Comment: "_compare a string variable called (code) to an array of strings_" A `String` will never be equal to a `String[]`

Comment: Yes that is correct thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your array to a List then use [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) to check if the list contain the code or not :

```
boolean check = Arrays.asList(badcodess).contains(code);
```

Comment: I wrote some code above I want to use an if statement, would that work ? since check in boolean i am checking if it is true or not correct?

Comment: @Jonathan you can just use `if (check){//do something}else{//do something else}` no need to use `check = true` this is an assignment and not comparing, to check if a `check` equals to true or not you need to use double equal

Comment: so your saying I dont have to write check = true ?

Comment: exactly just use `if(check)` it equivalent to ``if(check == true)``

Comment: OKAY I see if it contain the code do this if not do this check = true is not needed because if it equals true your going to do something anyway... I see i got it

Answer (score 2):

Your first option would not do what you expect to do. And even if `someArray.equals(anotherArray)` would do an element-wise comparison (which it doesn't) - you would need to have the special array contain all objects of the existing array, in the exact same order. In that sense: first understand why this approach is flawed in many ways, to then drop it.

The second option is fine, but if you really want to "improve" the whole thing - use `ArrayList` instead - which has a `contains()` method.